# If Statement Failing sometimes with id BoolValue Comparison?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, comparison, boolean

I am pulling data from the web that is formatted in JSON and when I parse the data using "ValueForKeyPath" it stores the string value as an id object.

So I store the data into a `NSMutableArray`
In the debugger window it shows all the elements added as (id) null.

I have an if statement

```
if ([[self.activeCategories objectAtIndex:selected] boolValue] == true)
```

Sometimes I would say 20% of the time it fails the if statement when it should not.
I was wondering if it was because the `self.activeCategories` is storing `id` types. Do I need to do `[NSString stringWithFormat@"%@", x]` to all the objects inside the array? It seems like when I just straight cast it by using (NSString *) it is still type `id` in the debugger.

It's a very strange error to me... as the error is not consistently reproducible.

Comment: `id` is just a generic type that can be cast to another type.  Your issue is that the elements are being added as a `null` object.  Why would you expect the `boolValue` to be `YES` for a null object?  Perhaps you should show the code for how you're adding the elements to the `NSMutableArray`

Comment: @iWasRobbed 1 and 0 are suppose to be stored as string. what's interesting is that if I use `[NSString stringWithFormat @"%@", data1]` instead of directly adding `data1` to the array the debugger will show up 1 and 0 instead of null (ids)...

Comment: When you use `valueForKeyPath` it does not necessarily return the object as an `NSString` but rather as a generic object with a type `id` which can be any number of different object types.  The main point is that when you're populating the `NSMutableArray`, something is breaking since it's populating it with `null` objects.  Without you posting code and an example of the JSON output, we really can't help.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like that:

```
if ([[self.activeCategories objectAtIndex:selected] boolValue])
```

According to that [article](http://iosdevelopertips.com/objective-c/of-bool-and-yes.html) a BOOL may hold values other than 0 and 1 which may fail the comparison.